# Проект вызвал срабатывание точки останова

Tags: c++, delete, heap, breakpoint

Суть задачи - получить параметрические уравнения составного кубического сплайна по точкам, прочитанным из файла. Код отрабатывает верно, однако при выходе выдает "проект вызвал срабатывание точки останова" и указывает на вот эту часть в файле xlocale:

```cpp
   void __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL operator delete(void* _Ptr) noexcept { // replace operator delete
        _CSTD free(_Ptr);
```

Видимо, это из-за того, что в моем коде есть `new`, но нет `delete`. Однако при добавлении `delete`, возникает ошибка:

```cpp
heap corruption detected after normal block #150. 
CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.
```

Возможно, я не в тех местах ставлю `delete`? (отметила комментариями места, куда их вставляла).

*А еще, когда задаешь массив из 4х точек и не ставишь `delete`, то все работает как надо без ошибок!*

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Файл с точками:

```
5
0 2
2.4 -1.4
3.2 0
3.9 5
4.8 2.1
```

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h> 

using namespace std;

void getdata(const char* filename, double**& xy, int& n)
{

    char str_1[256];

    std::ifstream in(filename);                       

    cout << "points" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        in >> str_1;
        xy[0][i] = std::stod(str_1);
        in >> str_1;
        xy[1][i] = std::stod(str_1);
        cout << xy[0][i] << " " << xy[1][i] << endl;
    }
    cout << "---------------" << endl;
    in.close();   

}

void Zero1D(double* &zero, int n )
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        zero[i] = 0;
    }
}

void Zero2D(double** &zero, int n)
{
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        zero[i] = new double[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            zero[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void Find_M(int n, double** &M, double a, double b, double* &d, double* &u)
{
    int N = n - 1;

    if (n < 5)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                M[1][1] = (2 + 3.0 / 2);
                M[1][2] = 1;
                M[1][3] = u[1] - 3 * (d[0] - a);
            }
            if (i >= 2 && (N - 2) == 1)
            {
                M[i][1] = 1;
                M[i][2] = (2 + (3.0 / 2));
                M[i][3] = u[N - 1] - 3 * (b - d[N - 1]);
            }
        }
    }

    if (n > 4)
    {
        cout << "n>4" << endl;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
        {
            if (i == 1)
            {
                M[1][1] = (2 + 3.0 / 2);
                M[1][2] = 1;
                for (int j = 3; j < n; j++)
                {
                    M[1][j] = 0;
                }
                M[1][N] = u[1] - 3 * (d[0] - a);
            }
            if ((i >= 2 && i <= N - 1) && (N - 2) != 1)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if ((i - 1) != j && i != j && (i + 1) != j)
                    {
                        M[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                M[i][i - 1] = 1;
                M[i][i] = 4;
                M[i][i + 1] = 1;
                M[i][N] = u[i];
            }
            if (i == N - 1)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if ((N - 2) != j && (N - 1) != j)
                    {
                        M[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                }
                M[i][N - 2] = 1;
                M[i][N - 1] = (2 + (3.0 / 2));
                M[i][N] = u[N - 1] - 3 * (b - d[N - 1]);
            }
        }

    }
}

void Find_m(int n, double**& M, double*& m, double a, double b, double*& d )
{
    int n2 = n - 2;
    int N = n - 1;
    double temp;

    //прямой ход
    for (int i = 1; i <= n2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= n2; j++)
        {
            temp = (M[j][i]) / (M[i][i]);
            for (int k = 1; k <= n2 + 1; k++)
            {
                M[j][k] = M[j][k] - M[i][k] * temp;
            }
        }
    }

    //обратный ход
    m[n2] = M[n2][n2 + 1] / M[n2][n2];

    for (int i = n2 - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        temp = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= n2; j++)
        {
            temp = temp + M[i][j] * m[j];
        }
        temp = M[i][n2 + 1] - temp;
        m[i] = temp / M[i][i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        m[i] = (3.0 / 1) * (d[0] - a) - m[i + 1] / 2;
    }

    m[N] = (3.0 / 1) * (b - d[N - 1]) - m[N - 1] / 2;
}

void Get_equation(double**& S, int n, double*& p, double*& d, double*& m, const double TR)
{
    // Формулы (7)
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        S[i - 1][0] = round(p[i - 1] * TR) / TR;
        S[i - 1][1] = round(TR * (d[i - 1] - ((2 * m[i - 1] + m[i]) / 6))) / TR;
        S[i - 1][2] = round(TR * (m[i - 1] / 2)) / TR;
        S[i - 1][3] = round(TR * ((m[i] - m[i - 1]) / (6 * 1))) / TR;

    }
}

void progon(double*& p, double a, double b, int n, double**& S)
{       

    double* m_param = new double[n];    //коэф. для поиска S
    double*& m = m_param;              
    double** M_param = new double* [n]; //коэф. для поиска m
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        M_param[i] = new double[n];
    }
    double**& M = M_param;
    //расчетн.константы
    double* d_param = new double[n];
    double*& d = d_param;
    double* u_param = new double[n];   
    double*& u = u_param;
    int N = n - 1;                      //кол-во пар;
    static const double TR = 10000000;  //окргуление до 7знаков после запятой

    //забиваем нулями
    Zero1D(d,n);
    Zero1D(m, n);
    Zero2D(M, n);

    //определяем d и u
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        d[i - 1] = (p[i] - p[i - 1]) ;      // формула (2)
    }
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        u[i] = 6 * (d[i] - d[i - 1]);       // формула (3)
    }

    //ищем коэф. уравнения

    Find_M(n,M,a,b,d,u);
//  delete [] u_param;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout << "M[" << i << "][" << j << "]=" << M[i][j]<<endl;
        }
    }
    Find_m(n, M, m, a, b, d);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "m[" << i << "]=" << m[i]<< endl;

    }

    Get_equation(S,n,p,d,m,TR);
    //delete [] d_param;
        //delete[] M_param;
    //delete[] m_param;
    Sleep(20);
}



int main()
{
    double a, b; //гран.условия - первая производная
    a = 0.5;
    b = 0.5;

    double** XY = new double* [2];
    int num_point;
    double**& xy = XY;
    int& n = num_point;

    char str_1[256];

    std::ifstream in("in1.txt");                        
    in >> n;                               // читаем количество точек
    cout << n << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        xy[i] = new double[n];
    }
    in.close();   

    getdata("in1.txt",xy,n); //собираем массив точек из txt файла

    //создаем хранилища под параметрические уравнения
    double** S_x = new double* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        S_x[i] = new double[n];
    }
    double** Sx = S_x;
    double** S_y = new double* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        S_y[i] = new double[n];
    }
    double** Sy = S_y;

    Zero2D(Sx, n);
    Zero2D(Sy, n);

    //получаем параметрические уравнения 
    progon(xy[0], a, b, n, Sx);
    progon(xy[0], a, b, n, Sy);

    //выводим на экран
    for (int i = 0; i < n -1; ++i)
    {
        cout << "x(t) = ("<< Sx[i][3]<<")*(x - ("<<i<<"))^3 "<<" + ("<<Sx[i][2]<<")*(x - ("<<i<<"))^2  + ("<<Sx[i][1]<<")*(x  - ("<<i<<"))  + ("<<Sx[i][0]<<")"<< endl;
        cout << "y(t) = ("<< Sy[i][3]<<")*(y - ("<<i<<"))^3 "<<" + ("<<Sy[i][2]<<")*(y - ("<<i<<"))^2  + ("<<Sy[i][1]<<")*(y  - ("<<i<<"))  + ("<<Sy[i][0]<<")"<< endl;
        cout << i<<endl;
    }
    Sleep(20);

        //delete [] S_y;
        //delete [] S_x;
        //delete [] XY;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```